# shifted database to different server - Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

I shifted database from from one server to another but i see the webiste loads without CSS, JS and also the link as below, where magento1 is root folder under mydomain.com

> magento1index.php/directory/currency/switch/currency/EUR/uenc/aHR0cDovL2thbWJzLmluL21hZ2VudG8yLw,,/?SID=0tk929pbs7vrl8ptjdcp04fkd2?___store=EUR

in similar way when i try to open admin

> magento1index.php/adminz/index/index/key/9fc93bc7d964f

there is no /  between `magento1index.php`/ ( Magento1 folder and `index.php`)

Please let me know what might be the issue

Comment: Did you change db details of new server in local.xml ?

Comment: i have not changed any thing , its was earlier DB name and user name, In phpmyadmin I did empty the database and then imported new db.                    Secondly - the files which are present is old server files.

Comment: Did you check base urls and flush cache?

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked ,   i just folwled this solutions https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/56351/magento-css-and-javascript-not-loading-due-to-using-file-system-path/222747#222747

Comment: Good that it worked.

Comment: kalyan can u help me in giving solution can you please let em know if there any solution Newsletter Subscriber - Grid not loading

I had database A -- A files where newsletter subscribers was not a problem at all it was displaying in admin

Database b - B files where newsletter subscribers only was a problem it was showing blank screen without grid, hence i shifted assuming there is problem in files so shifted database B to different server where we are using Files A , but now i see there is some issue in database can you please guide.

Comment: Mysql subscriber data is storing properly in newsletter_subscribe table in phpmyadmin

Comment: HI Kalyan, can you guid eme on this     https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224895/error-required-fields

Comment: Hi Swaroop, link is invalid, please re-check.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226102/magento-1-9-i-would-like-to-have-one-more-menu-navigatiob-new-products -- Kalyan can u guide me